# Can not start spark on my cluster

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

Information in log file spark-hadoop-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-master.outis as bellow:

[image]

And in log file spark-hadoop-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-master.out it says:

[image]

Help please.
My spark version is:spark-1.6.0-bin-without-hadoop.tgz
Scala version is:2.10.5
Hadoop version is:2.6.0

Comment: If you are using Yarn, it seems you have not packaged `sl4j` with your application jar. In case you are running on standalone mode, I believe the sl4j is not in the classpath. Either way, the spark nodes are not able to find depenedent sl4j. Which mode you are running spark on?

Comment: I think @Mohitt gave you the answer: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/spark-Exception-in-thread-quot-main-quot-java-lang/td-p/19544

Comment: Thanks, I added "export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(/opt/hadoop/bin/hadoop classpath)" in my spark-env.sh file and the probelem is gone. And I don't understand why. Thnaks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add slf4j.api-1.6.1.jar under $SPARK_HOME/lib directory on each spark workers node as well as on spark master node. Once done please restart the master/worker process.

Comment: OK, I will try later. Thanks very much for your responding.O(∩_∩)O~~